# How to change upload directory in Vtiger

Tags: vtiger

When user upload image in Vtiger (Producte module) created automatic path. Now image path has the form `/storage/2016/May/week2/26540_IMG_NAME.png`. I need chenge it to `/storage/product/IMG_NAME.png`. How I can do it?

Vtiger version 6.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change in  `\vtlib\Vtiger\Functions.php` to change the upload directory path.

-- Make sure that the directory you are created having read write permissions

```
static function initStorageFileDirectory() {
       //change the directory path by modifying the $filepath
}
```

Hope it will help you. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it should work. Maybe I did not know very well vtiger, but in my opinion to make changes directly in the library is not a good practice. When you update all of the changes will be lost. Perhaps there is some sort of option in the settings?

Comment: Another point. This allows you to change the path. but it does not allow to remove the prefix in the filename. In a file `\vtlib\Vtiger\Functions.php` I did not find these settings.

Comment: There is no setting to choice the directory to save uploaded documents. You have to do customization in code.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help.